# Javascript,selectedIndex property returns [object HTMLSelectElement] + the value

Tags: javascript, document.write, selectedindex

I have simple code to get the `value` of the *dropdown* list items and `write` it in the document.

```
Select a fruit and click the button:
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
  <option>Pineapple</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
</select>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Display index</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    x += x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;
    document.write("<br / >" + x);
}
</script>
```

I am facing two problems here,one is that the *result* is `[object HTMLSelectElement]+value`.Why is it happening ?

Second is that `document.write` property removes all the body elements and only displays its result.Why is it happening ? can you explain in detail.

Comment: I recommend you do some research on the basics of javascript.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would detail what are you trying to achieve here. As for document.write, you can think of it as throwing away your writing paper and laying down your new ideas on a fresh sheet of paper. It always does that.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    x += x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;
    document.write("<br / >" + x);
```

You're appending the value to `x` which is actually a Node of type `HTMLSelectElement`.

Instead it should be:

```
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect"),
    selectedValue = x.value;
    document.write("<br / >" + selectedValue);
```

Even you need not use `selectedIndex` etc, if you just use `document.getElementById("mySelect").value` it will give the selected value.

Regarding `document.write`, I would recommend you to refer **[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write)**

Instead of document.write you must ues `appendChild` or `innerHTML`.

```js
function myFunction() {
 var x = document.getElementById("mySelect"),
selectedValue = x.value;
document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = selectedValue;
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
  <option>Pineapple</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
</select>
<div id="result"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Display index</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are appending the content by using `+` sign as below:

```
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
x += x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;
document.write("<br / >" + x);
```

so remove `+` sign and it should give you selected index, as:

```
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
var selectedValue = x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;
document.write("<br / >" + x);
```

Secondly, you are using [document.write()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) which writes your string to entire document removing your entire content, so try writing your content to some div, as:

```
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
var selectedValue = x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;
document.getElementById("some_div").innerHTML = selectedValue;
```

where "**some_div**" is an `id` of a `div` tag which you can add in your html content

Comment: I tried you code but it just returned `[object HTMLSelectElement]`.

Comment: @JokerSpirit there was a typo, it works fine .. see:: http://jsfiddle.net/653knkon/

Answer (score 1):

For your first problem, you are getting the DOM element with ID 'myselect' to setting `x` to it here:

```
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
```

Then in this line, `x.options[x.selectedIndex].value` evaluates to a string. By doing +=, you are attaching/appending that string to the value contained in x. Javascript automatically converts the value of x to a string before appending, so you get the `[object HTMLSelectElement]+value` result.

```
x += x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;
```

Essentially you are doing `x = [object HTMLSelectElement] + x.options[x.selectedIndex].value` if that makes it clearer what's happening.

For your second problem, `document.write(value)` replaces whatever is in the document with `value`. For more information you can look at the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

Comment: Whoops didn't see the other answers as I was typing mine up.